# Force /news folder to HTTP in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

We have a section of our site which uses https to login securely, however when you visit this page and click away, you continue to view the site in HTTPS. This causes display issues on any pages using the http://www.domain.com/news/ URL.

How can we force all pages under the http://www.domain.com/news/ folder to use HTTP rather than HTTPS?

Comment: Don't go backwards. Push everything to HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

It's the opposite of requiring https, so with the condition of https on, rewrite this specific dir with deeper path to the http version.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^news/(.*) http://%{SERVER_NAME}/news/$1 [L]
```

Instead of SERVER_NAME, you can use HTTP_HOST when your site is accessed with a server-alias and you don't want to change that.

Be aware that links to https-requiring pages should be use https explicitly, or have a rewrite-rule of their own.

Answer (score 1):

Place this 301 redirect rule in `/news/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /news/

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```